# View composer is not working in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

I am creating a common composer for all views but it's not working correctly.

Create directory for composers in `App/Http/ViewComposers`.

Create a `MovieComposer.php` inside `ViewComposers`.

```
namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\View\View;

class MovieComposer
{
    public $movieList = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->movieList = [
        'Movie One',
        'Movie Two',
        'Movie Three',
        'Movie Four',
        'Movie Five'
        ];
    }

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('latestMovie', 'Hello');
    }
}
```

Create service provider for composers

```
php artisan make:provider ComposerServiceProvider
```

Register ComposerServiceProvider in config/app.php in providers

```
App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class,
```

Code inside `ComposerServiceProvider.php`

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // View::share('latestMovie', 'Hello world');

        View::composer('app', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\MovieComposer@compose');

        // view()->composer('app', function($view){
        //     $view->with('latestMovie', 'Hello world');
        // });

        // view()->composer(
        //   'app',
        //   'App\Http\ViewComposers\MovieComposer'
        // );
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

In this code **latestMovie** variable is global variable that use in all views but it's not working fine.

Error.

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Undefined variable: latestMovie (View: /home/rupendrakumardhiman/Projs/badass/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php) (View: /home/rupendrakumardhiman/Projs/badass/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your view composer attached view to `layouts.app`

```
View::composer('layouts.app', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\MovieComposer@compose');
```

or to a wildcard view

```
View::composer('*', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\MovieComposer@compose');
```

Keep in mind that a wildcard view will also be triggered for every @include used.

Answer (score 0):

```
View::composer('app', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\MovieComposer@compose');
```

You should not use that final @compose. If still problem persists, make sure you have a view named 'app' (name of the view file) that resides in your 'resources/views' directory.